# Python package to work with GIS data?

Tags: python, gis

For example, I would like to calculate a midpoint given latitude and longitude. Is there a Python package that already does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [Shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html), which is just a neat set of geographic tools. Off hand, I think something like this would work:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
points = MultiPoint([(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)])
print points.centroid #True centroid, not necessarily an existing point
```

Also, did you know there was a whole StackExchange site just for GIS software questions? [GIS.StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is really helpful.

Lastly, have you looked at [ArcPy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000v00000001000000)?

This is a library built up around ArcGIS by ESRI. Unfortunately, it requires a license. Lame. But if your project has corporate backing, it is an extremely flexible and powerful library for geographic problems.

Comment: I have also worked with shapely and found it very good. Arcpy is also a great option but you need to have arcgis license for that. If you only want to perform basic geographic operations like finding midpoint, then shapely is the best option.

Comment: @Dipto Oh! I totally forgot about the ArcGIS license! We just have a bunch of them. Thanks for the note, I will add that information.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at project [shapely](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely). It should allow you to work with GIS data in Python.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is for high latitude and/or covers thousands of kilometers, you may want to consider something like [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/other.html#python), which knows geodesic calculation, not assume cartesian coordinates.